# Maximum point of $ 1- \sqrt{x^2+y^2} $

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the function $ 1- \sqrt{x^2+y^2} $.

The point (0,0) clearly is the maximum point of the function, and it is also an inner point because $ f $ is defines for any (x,y). But the partial derivative according to $ x $ is not 0 at (0,0). How's that possible?

Comment: Your function is defined over $[0,+\infty)\times[0,+\infty]$ so $(0,0)$ is *not* an interior point of the domain. Hence, the necessary conditions for extrema don't apply.

Comment: @charlus How is that the domain? The *implicit* domain [points where rule defined] is all of $\mathbb{R}^2.$

Comment: @coffeemath my bad... I don't know what I was thinking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the map $(x,y) \mapsto \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$. Like the real map $x \mapsto \vert x \vert$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Assume we have a function $f$ where $f$ is not differntiable at, say, (0,0) just like in this example. What if ita not clear from the definition of $ f $ whether (0,0) is a maximim/minimum/neither, we cannot use the Hessian matrix in a case where the partial derivativea dosent vanish at (0,0). Is there a way to find out what the is the type of (0,0)?

Comment: A method can be to look if the map has critical points where it is differentiable. And to compare the values of the maps vs. the one where it is not differentiable by using comparison methods. Like here using that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \ge 0$.